# Full-Text-Search of database

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Iam looking for a performant way and readable way to implement a full-text-search. I have a lot of requirements for the serach. See this list below.

### Requirements

- **Peformance**
  My database growing up very fast. Load all data into HEAP an doing some `.stream()`-magic is not an option. The search should be performed by the DBMS.
- **Readability**
  I need easy a solution. A complex query like this [How to implement simple full text search in JPA (Spring Data JPA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917442/how-to-implement-simple-full-text-search-in-jpa-spring-data-jpa) (see option #2) is also not a solution. I would need some `JOIN`s and the resulting query is to complex.
  The overhead with an "index-field" is also not possible (to much joined data).
- **Concurrency**
  The application need to be scalable (with n-instances), so a solution with `Lucene` is not very good [here is an example](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search)
- **no mixing of technologies**
  I dont want to mix the logic into different systems. This means, the whole search-logic should be defined in Java. A combination of the Java-Logic with views or sql-functions should be avoided.

### Discovered options yet

1. [QueryDsl](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl)
   This is my old solution. But its very complex and produced a lot of problems with the automated generated classes.
2. [Lucence](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search)
   I like this. But there only one big problem: The index. Keep the index up2date on all instances is going a bit too overkill.
3. [Very long @Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917442/how-to-implement-simple-full-text-search-in-jpa-spring-data-jpa)
   The resulting query getting to complex to handle it.
4. `Java.stream()...`

   ```java
   // kinda
   getAllUsers().stream()
     .filter(user -> user.getName().contains(searchTerm)
       || user.getSex().contains(searchTerm) 
       || user.getAge().toString().equals(searchTerm) 
       || ...)
   ```

   I have to much data to do that. So this solution will also not scale well.
5. [Specification Interface](https://www.codementor.io/@milanflink/spring-advanced-search-filtering-utxf2wdm3)
   My preferred solution. But maybe there are other (and better) solutions?
6. `SearchFiled` or similar 
   Too many `JOINS`. Too much data.
7. ?

### Question

What are your expericenes with full-text-search in a Spring-Boot-Application? Do you know a solution that met my requierements?

Answer (score 1):

If you have reached till Lucene, then a step further is Solr. I haven't used the options you have mentioned above, but I have certainly worked with Solr and can safely say that it is worth a try, for speed and ease of use.

Out of the four constraints you have put, the first three are taken care of, I feel with Solr.

- **Performance**: Solr is a proven candidate in this area.
- **Readability**: I assume you mean readability of code. Though this depends upon the code and design are done, the Solr part is quite friendly to code, understand and maintain because of the lack of `JOIN` and other RDBMS concepts.
- **Concurrency**: From the official documentation at [lucene.apache.org/solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/introduction-to-scaling-and-distribution.html):

> Both Lucene and Solr were designed to scale to support large implementations with minimal custom coding.

and that Solr can do the following in this regard:

> - **distributing** an index across multiple servers
> - **replicating** an index on multiple servers
> - merging indexes

- **no mixing of technologies**: With the option of using Solr, you have at least two technologies: Java and Solr. I am not sure if you wanted to keep your solution to pure Java/JEE. If that is the case, then this may not satisfy that need.

However, this requirement:

> The search should be performed by the DBMS.

is **surely** not taken care of.

Also, can't think of a way ***other than a custom design*** for this:

> Keep the index up2date on all instances is a bit overkill.

**A warning:** It may take some time to get a good grasp on Solr if you are new to it.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider apache solr for searching